# C# directory scan performance

Tags: c#, io

I have a folder structure on a network drive that is

Booking Centre -> Facility -> Files

eg

- EUR/12345678/File_archive1.txt
- EUR/12345678/File_archive2.txt
- EUR/12345678/File_latest.txt
- EUR/5555/File_archive1.txt
- EUR/5555/File_archive2.txt
- EUR/5555/File_latest.txt

When a user selects a booking centre from the drop down, I want the code to look in the above network path for that booking centre, to look at all sub folders and find the most recent file in each of the sub folders and use that to populate a list of portfolios for a second dropdown. It is incredibly slow though, my code given below. Can anyone suggest a faster approach?

```
public IDictionary<string, Portfolio> ReadPortfolios()
{
    var portfolios = new Dictionary<string, Portfolio>();

    var di = new DirectoryInfo(PortfolioPath);
    var possibleFacilities = di.GetDirectories();

    foreach (var possibleFacility in possibleFacilities)
    {
        try
        {
            if (possibleFacility.GetFiles().Any())
            {
                var mostRecentFile = possibleFacility.GetFiles().OrderBy(file => file.LastWriteTimeUtc).Last();

                var portfolio = UnzipAndReadPortfolio(mostRecentFile);
                if (portfolio == null) continue;

                portfolios.Add(possibleFacility.Name, portfolio);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Failed to read portfolio: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    return portfolios;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can do a "Performance Analysis" in Visual Studio to check which method is slow? If you comment "UnzipAndReadPortfolio" is the proces faster?

Comment: You enumerate two times possibleFacility.GetFiles()

Comment: Could you precalculate and cache the results dictionary rather than recalculate it every time the dropdown is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested by all subdirectories of "PortFolioPath", try to use the overload of GetDirectories and / or GetFiles which allows you to pass the SearchOption.AllDirectories parameter : it will avoid multiple access to network.

You also have TWO calls of GetFiles() in your loop, you should rather store the result of first call in a local variable.

You don't provide the code of UnzipAndReadPortfolio, which is maybe the slowest part (... or not ?).

Remember : in your code often you can think "one method call = one network access". So try to flatten your loops, reduce FSO access, etc.

Comment: Please also note that ".Last()" in your code will throw an exception on an empty folder, even with null check under. Use LastOrDefault() instead.

Answer (score 1):

A probably real little performance gain

```
var mostRecentFile = possibleFacility.GetFiles()
                     .OrderBy(file => file.LastWriteTimeUtc)
                     .LastOrDefault();
if(mostRecentFile != null)
   ....
```

and comment out the first

```
// if(possibleFacility.GetFiles().Any())
```

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing:
Every time you call possibleFacility.GetFiles() you get all files within the folder. 
you have to call it and save it in a variable and then use this variable.